# Wrong keyboard layout after Xfce startup

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xfce4

When I start my laptop ([Debian Unstable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Naming_convention), [Xfce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce)) the keyboard layout is wrong and it uses the US keyboard layout, although the physical keyboard is German.

How can you set it to German?

The setting is German.

#### File */etc/default/keyboard*

```
# If you change any of the following variables and HAL and X are
# configured to use this file, then the changes will become visible to
# X only if HAL is restarted.  In Debian you need to run
# /etc/init.d/hal restart

# The following variables describe your keyboard and can have the same
# values as the XkbModel, XkbLayout, XkbVariant and XkbOptions options
# in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="de"
XKBVARIANT="nodeadkeys"
XKBOPTIONS=""

# If you don't want to use the XKB layout on the console, you can
# specify an alternative keymap.  Make sure it will be accessible
# before /usr is mounted.
# KMAP=/etc/console-setup/defkeymap.kmap.gz
BACKSPACE="guess"
```

And it actually claims that it uses the German layout in the Xfce keyboard layout switching panel. However, that panel lies and it uses the US layout, till I switch to US and back.

Comment: Where do you see this US keyboard? In the virtual console or in the X11 desktop?

Comment: It is only in X11

Comment: Then try *setxkbmap -print -verbose 10*. What does it say under *layout*?

Comment: Search engines lead to here, searching for the way to ***switch the keyboard layout in Xfce***. [A complaint from 2011](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=5785). I am considering posting an answer (a GUI-only is ***changing the order of the layouts*** in the keyboard panel), but does it apply to this situation?

Comment: Though one would imagine there would be a duplicate of that somewhere. Or maybe not, with only 89 questions total [tagged with Xfce](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/xfce4) (and an empty tag wiki).

Comment: Though that method does not seem reliable, e.g., after a restart of Linux. It seems to then require some shuffling of the order, reopen the panel, etc. (not 100% sure what the correct order of actions is to make it work).

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I ended up using KDE :/